# English to Arabic translation of web page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, language-translation

I have a very simple question and I need help here. I am developing a website with PHP and MySQL, request and response all through Ajax. On my index.php page all the data is shown from table A with a very simple query 'select * from A' my page is generated successfully. What I want now is a library or built-in feature which can convert the text of index.php in Arabic. 
I want this for all website but want to start from one page. I want Arabic users can use my website:)

Any help with example code will be of great help.

Comment: Automated translation is error prone. To accurately translate a page you'll need someone who can read English and write in Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine Translation is a very complicated process. Anyway, if you want your users to grasp the content of your website, I suggest that you use [Google Translate for Websites](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/).

Comment: i tried, but unable to do, can you give some example related to google translate for websites?

Comment: i tries looking for tutorials and techniques of conversion, but didnt find any, do you have any tutorial.